# Swift idiomatic error checking

Tags: swift, error-handling, idioms, nserror

Let's say that you have a function like this:

```
func getSomething(error: NSErrorPointer) -> Something
```

and you typically use it this way:

```
var error : NSError? = nil
let a = getSomething(&error)
```

What is an idiomatic way to check for error here? More specific questions:

1. If `error == nil` can we assume that `a` will never be nil and vice
   versa?
2. What should we check first: `error` (for its nilness) or `a` (to
   confirm that it's not a nil)?
3. Can `a != nil && error != nil` be true in some cases?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compare [Handling Error Objects Returned From Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1)
in the "Error Handling Programming Guide":

> **Important:** Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the
>   method. Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in
>   the Cocoa error domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the
>   method indicates failure by directly returning nil or NO, you should
>   always check that the return value is nil or NO before attempting to
>   do anything with the NSError object.

So for Cocoa/Cocoa Touch methods you should always check the return 
value first. It is guaranteed that `error != nil` if the method fails,
but it is not explicitly guaranteed that `error == nil` if the method succeeds.

Examples:

*JSON Serialization*

```
var error : NSError?
if let jsonObj = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) {
    // success
} else {
    // failure
    println("Invalid JSON data: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

*Core Data fetch request*

```
var error : NSError?
if let result = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) {
    // success, result has zero or more elements
} else {
    // failure
    println("Fetch failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

*Copying files*

```
var error : NSError?
if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(srcPath, toPath: dstPath, error: &error) {
    println("Cannot copy file: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Of course you can define your own rules for your own functions,
but I would follow the same Apple guidelines.

---

**Update: As of Swift 2,** Cocoa methods that produce errors are
translated to Swift functions that throw an error, and this error
must be handled with `try`-`catch`. Here is the Swift 2 version
of above examples:

*JSON Serialization*

```
do {
    let jsonObj = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
    // success
} catch let error as NSError {
    // failure
    print("Invalid JSON data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

*Core Data fetch request*

```
do {
    let result = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    // success, result has zero or more elements
} catch let error as NSError {
    // failure
    print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

*Copying files*

```
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(srcPath, toPath: dstPath)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Cannot copy file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Martin, thank you for excellent answer! Do you have any idea what is the motivation behind this logic? Why checking return value first and not the error?

Comment: @mikejd: I *think* I heard/read some time ago that a function might pass the error pointer to another lower-level function which fails and sets the error. If the higher-level function choses to ignore this error of the lower-level function and returns success, then the error object is still set. But I am not 100% sure, and I haven't actually observed this case.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

if a function returns an optional value i.e

```
func someFunc(someVar: String) -> NSData? {
  // some code
}
```

(the optional means that it can return a nil)
then error checking is pretty simple

```
if let data = someFunc("someString") {
  // this means there was NO error as the function didn't return a nil
}
else {
  // This means there was an error
}
```

This video is a pretty good reference for error checking and handling in swift https://youtu.be/m8szaLqHVDs

Comment: While `nil` return value may be a good hint of the failure, you also often need an _actual error_ to understand what exactly went wrong, don't you?

Comment: That depends and is quite subjective. but if a function provides the availability for an NSError pointer as a parameter then you could choose to use it or not.