# Xcode 7 beta NSURLConnection error

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, ios9, xcode7

I'm calling a function in my server and the app crashes, but it works fine on the simulator.
My code:

```
class func changeTweet(tweet:String)
{
let data = NSMutableData()
let urlPath: String = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/registerword?word=\(tweet)"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
let request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
let response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?
>=nil

//crashes on this line:
let dataVal: NSData = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: response) 

var err: NSErrorPointer
let string = NSString(data: dataVal, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
if let str = string
{
  print("Server Response: \(str)")
}
}
```

[PS: I already added the keys on the plist](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1563)

Comment: Why don't you replace the forced `try!` by a proper try-catch and print the error message in the case of a failure? That might give useful information about your problem.

Comment: @MartinR can you post an example here?

Comment: @MartinR the problem is... it works on simulator!

Comment: It is documented in "Catching and Handling an Error" in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation. Here are some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29384651/1187415.

Comment: Didi you change the URL ? 127.0.0.1 is the ip of the current device. If you are running the server on your mac it may be why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

let data: NSData = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)

It's the & in front of response that you need I think.