# Void return in Objective-C does not translate to Swift 2.0 Error flow

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I've noticed that if I create an objective-c function that returns void and accepts an NSError pointer, it will not translate to the swift do-catch error flow and I'll have to pass in a reference to an NSError like in previous versions of swift.

for example:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithError:(NSError **)error {
    // set the error in here
}
```

in swift:

```
var error: NSError?
anObject.doSomethingWithError(&error)

if error != nil {
    // do stuff
}
```

---

Where as if I return an objective-c object or bool, it will translate correctly:

```
- (NSString *)doSomethingWithError:(NSError **)error {

}
```

in swift:

```
do {
    let aString = try anObject.doSomething()
} catch {
    // stuff
}
```

---

Is there something about this that I don't understand, or is this just apple dropping the ball? I saw post that mentioned this a while ago: [blog post](http://blog.benjamin-encz.de/swift-error-handling-and-objective-c-interop-in-depth/)

Comment: [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

`You place an ampersand (&) directly before a variable’s name when you pass it as an argument to an inout parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the function.`

Comment: @ssrobbi: Here is a related Q&A about error checking that might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384218/swift-idiomatic-error-checking.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR , just needed to follow cocoa standards more closely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Cocoa conventions, it has never been correct to determine that a method failed by checking whether it set the error variable. You must always check the method return value before using the error variable. From the [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC):

> **Important:** Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the method. Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in the Cocoa error domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the method indicates failure by directly returning `nil` or `NO`, you should always check that the return value is `nil` or `NO` before attempting to do anything with the `NSError` object.

That convention is what Swift's error handling is based on. Internally, it must surely be checking the return value of methods to decide whether it must jump to a `catch` block.

Your first `-doSomethingWithError:` method with the `void` return does not follow Cocoa's conventions, so it's not surprising that Swift doesn't handle it the way you expect.

Comment: `That convention is what Swift's error handling is based on. Internally, it must surely be checking the return value of methods to decide whether it must jump to a catch block.`


That would make sense. So would I always return a boolean for success/failure then to conform to cocoa's standards? (and would also make the do-catch flow work correctly)

Comment: A boolean or an object pointer (where `nil` means failure), yes.